Privacy Reminder Elementor Wordpress
I used a template kit on elementor to create a website, and everytime I click on preview the website, a privacy reminder from the template appears and I don't know how to delete it. Can you help me please?
I deleted the downloaded template from my page but this remains here. Attached print screen.

you can just add the screenshoot link here in the comments

https://paste.pics/3bc882a585df3952ce18eccdb27a84de

Can someone please help me?
